# Replace all links in the body of html page using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have used the following code to replace all the links on HTML page.

```
$output = file_get_contents($turl);
$newOutput = str_replace('href="http', 'target="_parent"  href="hhttp://localhost/e/site.php?turl=http', $output);
$newOutput = str_replace('href="www.', 'target="_parent"  href="http://localhost/e/site.php?turl=www.', $newOutput);
$newOutput = str_replace('href="/', 'target="_parent"  href="http://localhost/e/site.php?turl='.$turl.'/', $newOutput);

echo $newOutput;
```

I want to modify this code to replace only links inside the body and not in the head.

Comment: I saw your comment that you need to keep the head. Look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decapitate the code.
Finds the body and separate the head from the body to two variables.

```
//$output = file_get_contents($turl);

$output = "<head> blablabla

 Bla bla
</head>
<body>
 Foobar
 </body>";

//Decapitation
$head = substr($output, 0, strpos($output, "<body>"));
$body = substr($output, strpos($output, "<body>"));
// Find body tag and parse body and head to each variable

$newOutput = str_replace('href="http', 'target="_parent"  href="hhttp://localhost/e/site.php?turl=http', $body);
$newOutput = str_replace('href="www.', 'target="_parent"  href="http://localhost/e/site.php?turl=www.', $newOutput);
$newOutput =  str_replace('href="/', 'target="_parent"  href="http://localhost/e/site.php?turl='.$turl.'/', $newOutput);

echo $head . $newOutput;
```

https://3v4l.org/WYcYP

Answer (score 6):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse and manipulate the source. It's always a better idea to use a dedicated parser for a task like this instead of using string operations.

```
// Parse the HTML into a document
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($html);

// Loop over all links within the `<body>` element
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    // Save the existing link
    $oldLink = $link->getAttribute('href');

    // Set the new target attribute
    $link->setAttribute('target', "_parent");

    // Prefix the link with the new URL
    $link->setAttribute('href', "http://localhost/e/site.php?turl=" . urlencode($oldLink));
}

// Output the result
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

See https://eval.in/843484

Comment: what about if I want to add parameters to the url also? `$link->setAttribute('href', "http://localhost/e/site.php?turl=" . urlencode($oldLink) . "&somethingElse=1");` will result in the href being: `http://localhost/e/site.php?turl=oldurl&amp;somethingElse=1`. How could I tell `DOMDocument` to not explicitly encode the ampersand symbol? Basically, what I want to do is fetch an url in the href, which may have many parameters, and send it through a different url with an additional hash in another parameter.